# MoneyFormatter::parseMoney throws MoneyFormatException

Tags: java, joda-money

Take this SSCCE (with Joda-Money library installed):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("100");
    MoneyFormatter mf = new MoneyFormatterBuilder().appendLiteral("$ ").appendAmount(MoneyAmountStyle.LOCALIZED_GROUPING).toFormatter();
    String money_as_string = mf.print(Money.of(CurrencyUnit.USD, bd)); // The MoneyFormatter is what printed this string...
    System.out.println(money_as_string);
    Money money = mf.parseMoney(money_as_string); // You think it should be able to parse the string it gave me, right?
}
```

I used the `MoneyFormatter` to print the `String`: `money_as_string`. My (reasonable?) expectation was that I could use the same `MoneyFormatter` to parse the string back into a `Money` object. But, alas, no dice. It throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.joda.money.format.MoneyFormatException: Parsing did not find both currency and amount: $ 100.00
    at org.joda.money.format.MoneyFormatter.parseBigMoney(MoneyFormatter.java:237)
    at org.joda.money.format.MoneyFormatter.parseMoney(MoneyFormatter.java:258)
    at test4.Test12.main(Test12.java:35)
```

So, my question is: how exactly does one get a `Money` object from a `String`?

EDIT: @durron597, your information was helpful but did not answer the question. How, exactly, do you go from a `String` to a `Money` object then?

I added code to remove the dollar sign:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("100");
    MoneyFormatter mf = new MoneyFormatterBuilder().appendLiteral("$ ").appendAmount(MoneyAmountStyle.LOCALIZED_GROUPING).toFormatter();
    String money_as_string = mf.print(Money.of(CurrencyUnit.USD, bd)); // The MoneyFormatter is what printed this string...
    System.out.println(money_as_string);
    Money money = mf.parseMoney(money_as_string.replace("$", "").trim()); // You think it should be able to parse the string it gave me, right?
}
```

and I got this:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.joda.money.format.MoneyFormatException: Text could not be parsed at index 0: 100.00
    at org.joda.money.format.MoneyFormatter.parseBigMoney(MoneyFormatter.java:233)
    at org.joda.money.format.MoneyFormatter.parseMoney(MoneyFormatter.java:258)
    at test4.Test12.main(Test12.java:35)
```

So, it can't parse the text with or without the currency symbol.

Can anyone get the `parseMoney()` function to work, ever??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the first thing that stood out to me is that you were using `appendLiteral` and not `appendCurrencySymbolLocalized` (what if you were using `CurrencyUnit.EUR`? You wouldn't want a $).

However, when you change it to this:

```
MoneyFormatter mf = new MoneyFormatterBuilder()
        .appendCurrencySymbolLocalized()
        .appendAmount(MoneyAmountStyle.LOCALIZED_GROUPING)
        .toFormatter();
```

Your code instead throws this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: MoneyFomatter has not been configured to be able to parse
    at org.joda.money.format.MoneyFormatter.parse(MoneyFormatter.java:281)
    at org.joda.money.format.MoneyFormatter.parseBigMoney(MoneyFormatter.java:229)
    at org.joda.money.format.MoneyFormatter.parseMoney(MoneyFormatter.java:258)
    at MoneyTest.main(MoneyTest.java:17)
```

Further examination reveals this telling line [in the javadoc](http://joda-money.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/money/format/MoneyFormatterBuilder.html#appendCurrencySymbolLocalized%28%29):

> appendCurrencySymbolLocalized
>
> `public`[`MoneyFormatterBuilder`](http://joda-money.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/money/format/MoneyFormatterBuilder.html)[`appendCurrencySymbolLocalized()`](http://joda-money.sourceforge.net/apidocs/src-html/org/joda/money/format/MoneyFormatterBuilder.html#line.141)
>
> Appends the localized currency symbol to the builder.
>   The localized currency symbol is the symbol as chosen by the locale of the formatter.
>
> **Symbols cannot be parsed.**
>
> Returns: this, for chaining, never null

Why might that be? Probably because **currency symbols are ambiguous**. [Many countries use a dollar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollar#Economies_that_use_a_dollar). Here are some [examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollar_sign#Currencies_that_use_the_dollar_or_peso_sign):

> In addition to those countries of the world that use dollars or pesos, a number of other countries use the $ symbol to denote their currencies, including:
>
> - Nicaraguan córdoba (usually written as C$)
> - Samoan tālā (a transliteration of the word dollar)
> - Tongan paʻanga
> - Zimbabwe (usually written as Z$)

---

Try this code:

```
MoneyFormatter mf = new MoneyFormatterBuilder()
        .appendCurrencyCode()
        .appendAmount(MoneyAmountStyle.LOCALIZED_GROUPING)
        .toFormatter();
```

This will make something like `USD 100.00` print, which will be parsed properly. If you absolutely must have the dollar symbol, you are going to need to implement your own printer/parser. Or you could use this one:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

import org.joda.money.BigMoney;
import org.joda.money.CurrencyUnit;
import org.joda.money.IllegalCurrencyException;
import org.joda.money.Money;
import org.joda.money.format.MoneyAmountStyle;
import org.joda.money.format.MoneyFormatter;
import org.joda.money.format.MoneyFormatterBuilder;
import org.joda.money.format.MoneyParseContext;
import org.joda.money.format.MoneyParser;
import org.joda.money.format.MoneyPrintContext;
import org.joda.money.format.MoneyPrinter;

public class MoneyTest {
    private static enum DollarParserPrinter implements MoneyParser,
            MoneyPrinter {
        INSTANCE;

        private static final String DOLLAR_SYMBOL = "$ ";

        @Override
        public void parse(MoneyParseContext context) {
            int endPos = context.getIndex() + 2;
            if (endPos > context.getTextLength()) {
                context.setError();
            } else {
                String code =
                        context.getTextSubstring(context.getIndex(), endPos);
                if(DOLLAR_SYMBOL.equals(code)) {
                    context.setCurrency(CurrencyUnit.USD);
                    context.setIndex(endPos);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void print(MoneyPrintContext context, Appendable appendable,
                BigMoney money) throws IOException {
            if(CurrencyUnit.USD == money.getCurrencyUnit()) {
                appendable.append(DOLLAR_SYMBOL);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalCurrencyException("This parser only knows how to print US Dollar money!");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("100");
        MoneyFormatter mf =
                new MoneyFormatterBuilder().append(DollarParserPrinter.INSTANCE, DollarParserPrinter.INSTANCE)
                        .appendAmount(MoneyAmountStyle.LOCALIZED_GROUPING)
                        .toFormatter();
        String money_as_string = mf.print(Money.of(CurrencyUnit.USD, bd)); 
        System.out.println(money_as_string);
        Money money = mf.parseMoney(money_as_string);
        System.out.println(money);
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited my answer in response to you.